# maintaining order of test execution when parametrizing tests in test class

Tags: python, pytest

I am trying to parametrize my tests like below

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("a,b", test_data)
class TestClass():
    def test_A(self,a,b):
        # Some Code ..
        pass
    def test_B(self,a,b):
        # Some Code ..
        pass
    def test_C(self,a,b):
        # Some Code ..
        pass
```

I want my test to be executed in Sequential order like test steps, e.g

```
test_A
test_B
test_C
test_A
test_B
test_C
....
```

The order in which they are getting executed is

```
test_A
test_A
...
test_B
test_B
...
test_C
test_C
```

The other option I have tried is by putting my tests in for loop like below

```
for data in test_data:
    a,b = data
    def test_A(a,b):
        # Some Code ..
        pass
    def test_B(a,b):
        # Some Code ..
        pass
    def test_C(a,b):
        # Some Code ..
        pass
```

This give me the desired order but test names remains same in all the iteration so it creates problem in reporting.

Comment: Good unittests shouldn't care about order. pytest has [fixtures](http://pytest.org/latest/fixture.html) for doing setup/teardown style things.

Comment: In general I agree but  there can always be specific requirement. My tests are independent in a sense that if B executes before A or C executes before B it doesn't matter. Only requirement is A,B and C all should first execute for 1 set of data and then for second set.

Comment: Why do you need to run them in a specific order?

Comment: Because for each input parameter there is some configuration need to be done in UUT which is a time taking effort. So I only want to do it once for each set of Data

Comment: pytest fixtures can do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was finally able to acheive this using pytest_generate_tests hook.

```
def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    argvalues = []
    for data in metafunc.cls.data:
        items = data.items()
        argnames = [x[0] for x in items]
        argvalues.append(([x[1] for x in items]))
    metafunc.parametrize(argnames, argvalues, scope="class"

class TestClass:
    data = [{'attr_1': 'val_1_1', 'attr_2': 'val_1_2'}, {'attr_1': 'val_2_1', 'attr_2': 'val_2_2'}]

    def test_A(self, attr_1, attr_2)
    ...

    def test_B(self, attr_1, attr_2)
    ...

    def test_B(self, attr_1, attr_2)
    ...
```

https://pytest.org/latest/example/parametrize.html