# PyTest Parametrized Test in order

Tags: python, pytest, parameterized-tests, pytest-order

I have 2 pyTest test cases that take a parameter. I want to run them in order with both params, instead of the first test running with all possible values, and then the 2nd test starting.

Consider the below test code:

```py
import pytest


@pytest.mark.parametrize("param1", [("A"), ("B")])
class TestClassTests:
    def test_01_test(self, param1):
        ...

    def test_02_test(self, param1):
        ...
```

The execution order I am getting is:

1. test_01_test -- (A)
2. test_01_test -- (B)
3. test_02_test -- (A)
4. test_02_test -- (B)

I want the order to be:

1. test_01_test -- (A)
2. test_02_test -- (A)
3. test_01_test -- (B)
4. test_02_test -- (B)

Answer (score 6):

Got answer from here: [maintaining order of test execution when parametrizing tests in test class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31957216/maintaining-order-of-test-execution-when-parametrizing-tests-in-test-class)

Just needs a scope="class" in the parametrize decorator.

```py
import pytest


@pytest.mark.parametrize("param1", [("A"), ("B")], scope="class")
class TestClassTests:
    def test_01_test(self, param1):
        ...

    def test_02_test(self, param1):
        ...
```

Comment: thanks i as about to rewrite the whole 'pytest_collection_modifyitems'